# does this work in Ubuntu correctly - or is there missing something?

Tags: iso, dvd, command-line, dd

This (gawky) question is concerning command dd:

> dd if=/dev/DVD of=whatever.iso

seems not to work ... and then output follows like:

> could not open /dev/DVD - file or directory not found

Is here usage of dd incomplete or not exactly enough - or path simply not correct ?

I wonder about that (this usb-dvd-burner) is not written in /etc/fstab - but

> wodim -v -eject whatever.iso

has no trouble to burn iso-images contrary to command dd ?

Comment: try /dev/dvdrw .

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/63924/how-can-i-backup-compact-disc-media-to-iso-files-on-ubuntu - your `if` may be `/dev/sr0` rather than any mountpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, commands, file names, etc. are all case sensitive. Try using

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=whatever.iso
```

instead of

```
dd if=/dev/DVD of=whatever.iso
```

Also, you can list the contents of `/dev` to make sure `/dev/dvd` exists, by typing `ls /dev`.